# How to use callbacks when specific variable is updated inside different functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm aware that we can use useEffect to set callbacks to state changes involving specific variables, but when I was refactoring a class component to one that uses hooks I encountered a problem, I set the state of a variable in three different functions (using setState), and each time I call a different callback for these setStates.

If I declare a useEffect like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
   callback1();
   callback2();
   callback3();
}, [myVariable]);
```

Each time `myVariable` changes I will call those 3 callback functions, which is not my intent, since they interfere with each other.

To clarify things, this is what I was doing in the class component:

```
function a () {
  ...
  this.setState({myVariable: x}, () => do something that involves myVariable);
};

function b () {
  ...
  this.setState({myVariable: y}, () => do another thing that involves myVariable);
};

function c () {
  ...
  this.setState({myVariable: z}, () => do another thing that involves myVariable);
};
```

How to proceed and create a specif callback for each `setMyVariable` call?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: The last argument in `useEffect` needs to be an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not call the correct callback function directly in the function where you're calling `setMyVariable()`?

Comment: Since the setMyVariable() is asynchronous and in my callbacks I need the state variable that was updated, I have to be sure it has changed via useEffect callback or so

Comment: But if you're setting the variable you must know the value inside the function from where you're setting it? So you can just pass it to both `setMyVariable(newValue)` and `callback1(newValue) `

Comment: Oh, you mean not even use the state variable?
That would work!
I was so focused on find a way to callback like when using setState that I didn't think about that.

Comment: Yes indeed, you might still want to use the state if you need the value somewhere else in your component but if you don't then you can get rid of it.

Comment: The problem is that the callback function uses a state variable, and is called in three different places, it just feels weird having to pass a value parameter instead of using the state variable. Also, if I want to call something only after the re-render of the page? So many downsides... hahaha

Answer (score 0):

use multiple `useEffects`

```
useEffect(() => {
   callback1();
}, [myVariable1]);


useEffect(() => {
   callback2();
}, [myVariable2]);
```

Comment: This is using a different variable inside the dependency array of each useEffect, I have only one variable that gets updated inside those functions.